# Figure labels not showing up

Tags: graphics, labels

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Introduction

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \label{fig:a}
  \caption{Image a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \label{fig:b}
   \caption{Image b}
\end{figure}

Comparison of Fig. \ref{fig:a} to Fig. \ref{fig:b}.

\end{document}
```

After running `pdflatex` on the document twice, the figure labels do not show up:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Put \label after \caption.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That helped